# Are there any strong forms of "clamped" induction?

Tags: number-theory, logic, proof-writing, induction, propositional-calculus

So in normal induction, we say that if $P(a)$ is true, and $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$, then $P(n)$ is true $\forall n\geq a$.

Then we have strong induction where you assume all preceeding values of the statement are true, or backwards induction where you show there are an infinite number of true statements and show that it holds backwards.

[Here](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Different%20kinds%20of%20Mathematical%20Induction.pdf) is a document that includes various forms of induction. I am however looking for a unique form of induction that is a mixture of these methods.

Assume that we know that $P(1)$ is true, and that $P(n)$ is true $\forall n\geq K$ where $K$ is some finite number. Now we only need to prove $P(n)$ for $1<n<K$.

My first thought was to "hop around" and show that $P(n)\land P(n+2) \implies P(n+1)$ and then have that fold in like an accordian when it hits the edges, however plugging this in to a truth table it seems to work in the situation where all are true, as well as when all are false, which is bad.

Does there exist any induction method that can take advantage of the fact that we are provably bounded on both sides?

Comment: You could make use of the tautology: $\forall x(P(x)\implies P(f(x))\vdash\forall x(P(x)\implies P(f(f(x))))$. Then, you can substitute f(x) for the successor function if you wish to work forward, or the precursor function if you wish to work backward. This means you can approach the problem from either side of the bounds. 
If you wished to, you could make f(x):=s(s(x)), so you prove something for every second case, if that makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: I don't think one exists because there are many cases in math where we know something is true for large $n,$ and we know it's true for some trivial  case like $n=1,$ but it takes a lot of hard work to show the cases inbetween. I'll think of an easy example and post in the answers soon.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such method in general. Maybe there are special cases in the literature for special problems.

For example, take an easy induction problem for $n$ large enough, like showing

$$2^n >n^3$$ for all $n\ge 0$. For $n=0, n=1$ it's clearly true. Now for $n=2$ through $n=9$ (where $2^9=512$ and $9^3=729$) it's false. But it's true for all $n\ge 10,$ and the obvious method of proof here is by induction.

There are many such problems, including serious research level problems where inbetween cases are just false, or if not impossible to prove, at least extremely hard to prove.

Comment: I understand that its not always the case that being bounded on both sides implies that the finite cases in the middle will also be true, but are there methods that can prove between whether or not all middle cases are true? It appears you are saying that no such method (currently) exists I just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: There are plenty of techniques in math (e.g. Interpolation) that are made to prove something in between. For example, maybe if you have a convex function in some sense, and you know endpoints, you could prove everything inbetween. What I'm saying is I've never seen this applied to induction before, and that there are well known problems where this is impossible. It would probably be the case that induction isn't necessary to prove it, and you would just combine methods arbitrarily. Maybe for AMGM inequality there is a way to do what you said, but it would just use convexity.